# Color palette issue when overlaying layers in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, canvas, openlayers

I'm trying to draw a temperature heatmap layer on top of the map. But here the problem arises that the heat map overlaps the names of cities, as in the first screen.

[image: as in the first screen]

When adding opacity, the color palette changes and the names of cities are still not clearly visible

[image: example 2nd screenshot].

And finally, when adding the property

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
```

I achieve the desired result, but the heatmap itself changes the palette, probably due to mixing colors with the bottom layer.

[image: Example]

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions in which direction to move, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Introducing a toggle between normal map (with names) and heatmap would help keep both maps separate, but in the same viewing area.

Comment: Put the labels on top (some basemap vendors provides this information, or create your own), and maybe a few important other layers (boundaries, main roads etc). Also if you have lots of "0" in the heat map, make this class fully transparent

Comment: Try putting a grayscale filter on the basemap as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/semi-transparent-layer.html

Comment: The css filter will not work in conjunction with `mutiply`, but you can also grayscale the basemap with a `color` operation https://codesandbox.io/s/semi-transparent-layer-forked-uncyj0?file=/main.js